# Return part of string with RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, string, search

First of all, Sorry, I'm newbie in Regular Expression so I cannot found the format for my RegEx.

I have a string like this :

```
{
   "xs:schema" : {
      "xs:element" : {
         "xs:complexType" : {
            "xs:choice" : {
               "xs:element" : {
                  "xs:complexType" : {
                     "xs:sequence" : {
                        "xs:element":null
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "diffgr:diffgram" : {
      "NewDataSet" : {
         "Table" : {
            "Item1" : 12345,
            "Item2":"Part"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I want select just this part of my string:

```
  "NewDataSet" : {
     "Table" : {
        "Item1" : 12345,
        "Item2":"Part"
     }
  }
```

how can I do it ?

Comment: You should not use a regex for that but parse the JSON and get the desired part trivially.

Comment: Thanks but JSON name is `diffgr:diffgram` I don't know how can I call this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to solve this easily just using JSON serialization. For example:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonText);
var partOfJson = JSON.stringify(obj["diffgr:diffgram"]);
```

OP said somewhere:

> Thanks but JSON name is diffgr:diffgram I don't know how can I call
>   this !

In JavaScript, objects can be used as associative arrays or even dictionaries. That is, their *properties* can be retrieved using *key-value* syntax instead of *dot syntax*.

Comment: Thanks for your comment "In JavaScript, objects can be used as associative arrays or even dictionaries", I forgot this option, Thanks